# convert to show percentage of the sum of 2 or more combined columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have looked at the similar questions and was unable to find anything that answered my question.

I have a column that is the calculation of other columns of which sum I would like to divide by a set number and show results in percentage from. I have tried the below query and am able to show in decimal. Basically find out what percentage of UPH an associate is doing...This way I can tell if they are slacking in their department or exceling. I am using 150 as my base rate

```
SELECT  
ID
  , DeptCode AS 'DC'
  , OpCode AS 'OC' 
  ,Units = sum(Units)
  ,UPH = cast(isnull(sum(Units) / nullif(sum(datediff(minute,StartTime,FinishTime))*1.0,0),0.0)*60  as decimal(10,0))
  ,Percentage = cast(isnull(sum(Units) / nullif(sum(datediff(minute,StartTime,FinishTime))*1.0,0),0.0)*60  as decimal(10,0)) / 150 


FROM dbo.TimeLog 
 WITH (NOLOCK)

WHERE DeptCode = 'FB'
  and OpCode   = 'PU'
  and Units IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
    ID
  , DeptCode
  , OpCode
```

Here is my result...

```
ID      DC  OC  Units   UPH Percentage
11259   FB  PU  553     114 0.760000
2375935 FB  PU  263     70  0.466666
```

I would like to see column 'Percentage' like the below

```
ID      DC  OC  Units   UPH Percentage
11259   FB  PU  553     114 76%
2375935 FB  PU  263     70  47%
```

Any help would be appreciated and I apologize in advance if this is elementary for a lot you, I am relatively new to SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead (SQL 2012 and later):

> Percentage = CONCAT(cast(isnull(sum(Units) /
>   nullif(sum(datediff(minute,StartTime,FinishTime))*1.0,0),0.0)*60  as
>   decimal(10,0)), '%')

Refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql

Try this instead (SQL 2008):

> (convert(varchar,cast((isnull(sum(Units) / nullif(sum(datediff(minute,StartTime,FinishTime))*1.0,0),0.0)*60)/150*100 as as decimal(10,0))) + '%') as Percentage

Refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/string-concatenation-transact-sql

Comment: Hi, I just tried that.... Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 26
'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.  Running SQL 2008R2

Comment: ran the second got this error code. Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 17
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Comment: try the aforementioned query now

Comment: oh wait one last question,  This is only showing me the percentage of the UPH I want to divide the number of the UPH by a set number,  say its 150...

Comment: it would be same. you need to.. (cast(isnull(sum(Units) / nullif(sum(datediff(minute,StartTime,FinishTime))*1.0,0),0.0)*60) / 150 ....

Comment: try something like this: 
(convert(varchar, (cast(isnull(sum(Units) / nullif(sum(datediff(minute,StartTime,FinishTime))*1.0,0),0.0)*60)/150 as decimal(10,0))) + '%') as Percentage
....given you want to divide by a set number like 150. let me know if this works. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145923/discussion-between-druidruid-and-somdip-dey).

Answer (score 0):

You can use format(decimal, 'p') as below:

```
      ,Percentage = Format(cast(isnull(sum(Units) / nullif(sum(datediff(minute,StartTime,FinishTime))*1.0,0),0.0)*60  as decimal(10,0)) / 100 , 'p')
```

Comment: 'Format' is not a recognized built-in function name. Im running 2008R2

Comment: Gotcha... Format is there from 2012 only